# What EOL character does Android use?

Tags: git, shell, command-line

I was wanting to know what EOL character Android uses. This is because I want to know what to update the *git --global core.autocrlf* value to? I am using git in Termux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is effectively Linux under the hood, and Linux is a type of Unix, so Android uses a single LF as the end of line character.

Note that even on Windows, you can full well use LF in almost all cases, since most languages and text editors handle a single LF just fine.  In fact, it's usually much better to configure your `.gitattributes` file appropriate with `text` and `eol` attributes, and then not set `core.autocrlf` at all, since that results in much more predictable behaviour altogether.